# Subset (Comprehension, Separation) Axiom and Definability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Moshe Machover's book, *Set Theory, Logic, and Their Limitations*, and on p. 19 he states that if $A\cup B$ is a set, then $A$ and $B$ are too by the Subset Axiom.  But this confuses me.  Clearly, $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $A\cup B$.  But how do we know that they are definable?  (Similarly, if $A$ is a class of sets, and $\cup A$ is a set, then I take it that $A$ is supposed to be a set by Powerset and Subset.  But my question re-arises here.)  I'm obviously missing something basic.  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I don't own a copy of this book and thus cannot check the validity or the context of this statement. Thus, it may be the case that the author's claim is not technically false. However, as stated here, it does not hold.

Comment: Thanks -- FYI, author writes the following.  "AuB is a set if/f A and B are sets.  Proof: If A and B are sets, then AuB = U{A, B}, which is a set by [Pairing] and [Union].  The converse follows easily from [the Subset Axiom]."

Comment: What is the 'subset axiom'? Sounds like he might be referring to some informal, naïve set theory. (Maybe, it's just the axiom of separation - sometimes also known as the axiom of comprehension.)

Comment: OK, maybe you're right.  While he's not using Naive Comprehension, the Axiom is formulated: "If B [is a subset of] A, and A is a set, then so is B."  But he immediately follows this with: "Zermelo's formulation of [the Subset Axiom], clearly equivalent to the one used here, said...that if A is a set then the class {x element of A : Px } is always a set."  However, the latter formulation seems like the standard one.

Comment: Coincidentally: is it known that the first formulation is consistent, if standard set theory is?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess that's obvious (just use a model where all the subsets are definable).

Comment: The first formulation is a tautololgy. If $B$ is a subset of some set $A$, then - by the definition of subset - it is a set. So.. yeah... it is a set. This doesn't allow us, however, to construct any new subset from $A$ that we didn't already have to begin with.

Comment: Good point!  And if we replaced it with "any subclass of a set is a set" we'd just be back to the original formulation (absent a non-standard theory of classes).

Comment: Now, that's different. If we define subclass (and class) in the sense of virtual class, i.e. all of our classes are of the form $\{x \mid \phi(x,p_1, \ldots, p_n) \}$, where $\phi$ is a formula of set theory and $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ are sets that we use as parameters, then his formulation is indeed equivalent to comprehension. And for virtual classes $A,B$ we indeed have that $A \cup B$ is a set iff $A$ and $B$ are sets.

Comment: (Note that while this fact is expressible for any fixed pair $A,B$ of virtual classes, the result for all virtual classes $A,B$ still is not expressible in the language of set theory, since the truth predicate is provably not definable.)

Comment: Got it -- thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your set theory is sufficiently strong, this is not true:

Let $M$ be a countable transitive model of some large fragment of your set theory. Then there is a subset $X \subseteq \omega$ such that $X \not \in M$ (since $M$ is countable). If $\omega \setminus X$ were in $M$, then so would $X$ be (because we can correctly calculate complements in $M$). Hence $X, \omega \setminus X \not \in M$, but $\omega = X \cup (\omega \setminus X) \in M$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  So, e.g., in ZFC the theorem stated is false?

Comment: @davidp Yes, in ZFC and much weaker theories, this statement is consistently false.

Comment: @davidp: The problem is with the notion of $A$ and $B$ to begin with. What are these objects and where do they exist?

Comment: Thank you!  I was worried that I didn't understand the content of the Subset Axiom after all.

Comment: @david Note also that his claim is not expressible in the language of set theory. In order to quantify over $A,B$, they must exist as objects and therefore must be sets. So, yeah, without having any additional information on the context, this seems rather odd.

Comment: Stefan, that is only true if you quantify over $A$ and $B$. You can see this as a schema of theorems; or just one meta-theorem if you insist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, that's what I was trying to bring across.

Answer (score 1):

*Classes* are defined as "extensions" of properties [page 16].

The "universe of discourse" is made of *sets* and *individuals*.

> A class that is not a set is called a *proper class*; a proper class is not 
>   an object, and therefore cannot be a member of any class [page 16].

Thus, *sets* are those that some axiom of the theory claims that they exists, like e.g.

> *3.2. Axiom of Pairing (A2)* : For all objects $a$ and $b$ the class $\{ a, b \}$ is a set [page 17],

or some theorem of the theory proves that they exists, like e.g.

> *3.9. Theorem* : $\emptyset$ is a set [page 18].

We have that: *3.14. Definition* [page 19] defines the *union* (or *join*) $A \cup B$ of two *classes* $A$ and $B$, which - of course - is a class.

We do not know that, in general, $A \cup B$ is a *set*, but we can prove it:

> *3.15. Theorem*: $A \cup B$ is a set iff both $A$ and $B$ are sets.

The first part: if $A,B$ are set, then also $A \cup B$ is, is proved by *Axiom of Pairing (A2)* and *Axiom of Union set (AU)*.

The second part: if $A \cup B$ is a set, then also $A,B$ are, is proved through:

> *3.6. Axiom of Subsets (AS)* : If $B \subseteq A$ and $A$ is a set then so is $B$.

We know that $A \cup B = \{x : x \in A \text { or } x \in B \}$ is a set; but, e.g. $B \subseteq A \cup B$, and thus by *AS* also $B$ is a set (the same for $A$).

For $B \subseteq A \cup B$, we have to apply:

> *3.4. Definition*: Let $A$ and $B$ be classes. If every member of $B$ is also a member of $A$, we say that $B$ is a *subclass* of $A$, briefly: $B \subseteq A$.

Clearly, if $a \in B$, then $a \in B$ or $a \in A$, and thus $a \in A \cup B$.

Comment: Thanks for putting this question into context. So, the author is right about his claim, it's just that they lacked context in the original post.

Comment: Hi, Mauro.  Thanks for this follow-up.  Is the point that A u B is really shorthand for the predicate x ∈ A & x ∈ B, so A and B are automatically definable?

Comment: @davidp - a *class* $A$ is specified by a *property* $P$, i.e. $x \in A$ **iff** $P(x)$. Thus, the class $A \cup B$ is specified by the property: $P_A(x) \lor P_B(x)$ (**or**, not **and**).

Comment: Hi, Mauro.  Thanks for the response.  I'm having trouble getting my head around this way of setting things up.  We can talk in the theory about things that the theory doesn't prove exist, right?  How would one express the claim that I took the author to be making in the current framework?

Comment: (The theory shouldn't prejudge that every set corresponds to a predicate, right?)